# regexp mulibyte characters and utf-8 support

Tags: mysql, regex, database, oracle, utf-8

I am handling some non ASCII data (in my case Arabic data) and I need to use regular expressions for some requests.

The problem is that the multi-byte is not supported for several DBMS, or causes various issues or wrong results.

- From MySQL 5.7 official documentation:
  http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/regexp.html

> **Warning**
>
> The REGEXP and RLIKE operators work in byte-wise fashion, so
> they are not multibyte safe and may produce unexpected results with
> multibyte character sets. In addition, these operators compare
> characters by their byte values and accented characters may not
> compare as equal even if a given collation treats them as equal.

- For Oracle Database: Multilingual Enhancement is not supported for several regex opperators.
  https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/appdev.102/b14251/adfns_regexp.htm#g692318
- For PostgresSQL, there is no chance for versions older than 9.0 but for the 9.0 seems also have some specific precautions to take into considerations:
  http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.3/static/functions-matching.html

> Numeric character-entry escapes specifying values outside the ASCII
> range (0-127) have meanings dependent on the database encoding. When
> the encoding is UTF-8, escape values are equivalent to Unicode code
> points, for example \u1234 means the character U+1234. For other
> multibyte encodings, character-entry escapes usually just specify the
> concatenation of the byte values for the character. If the escape
> value does not correspond to any legal character in the database
> encoding, no error will be raised, but it will never match any data.

Is there any DBMS or alternative data store which supports regex for multibyte data ?

Comment: Did you try with PostgreSQL?

Comment: I checked the official doc of postgresql, but I didn't find a direct answer. There is some chances with the version 9. http://grokbase.com/t/postgresql/pgsql-general/115zeef03p/utf-8-and-regular-expression

Comment: Yes, me too, that's why you need to make some tests.

Comment: Please provide samples of the regexps you would like to use.  There may be workarounds.